# Find finish button in selenium + python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

my stack is Selenium + Python

When i try to use "durty" Xpath everything is working fine: `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/app/div/payment-page/payment/div/credit-card/payment-response/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button"))).click()`

P.S: "Finish button will be active after clicking on the "Yes" button, so i cant click it just when this window is appear

But, when i try to make it beatiful - nothing is working fine. Here is my examples that i use, but always  appear:

> "Exception has occurred: TimeoutException"

1. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//unique_parent//input[@type='button' and @class='primary-button bounce-in']"))).click()`
2. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='button' and @class='primary-button bounce-in']"))).click()`
3. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type, 'button' and @class, 'primary-button bounce-in']"))).click()`
4. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@type, 'button' and @class, 'primary-button bounce-in']"))).click()`
5. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@type='button' and @class='primary-button bounce-in']"))).click()`
6. `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='button' and @class='primary-button bounce-in']"))).click()`
7. `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type, 'button' and @class, 'primary-button bounce-in']"))).click()`
8. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'primary-button bounce-in')]"))).click()`
9. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Finish')]"))).click()`

Here is DOM screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buQ28.png)

Comment: I can write it here, btw:

So idea is - I need to check that "green arrow" number same with "red arrow" number. THIS NUMBERS always generate with different numbers. So i make a variables "first_value" for the "red arrow" and "second_value" for the "green arrow"

I use ugly Xpath, maybe you help me with beautiful Xpath, please?

https://i.imgur.com/ZObrgb4.png

Comment: @amruta-pande can you please give me your email, so i cant contact with you for a question above, please?

Xpaths: 

first_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]"))).text
    second_value = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"), (first_value)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Finish']))